# Set of cardinality continuum contains a perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, transfinite-recursion

I want to make sure if my claim is true or false :

Every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of cardinality continuum contains a perfect set

A perfect set is a closed set with no isolated point. It might be there is a counter-example but I did not see it or claim needs to be proved. Any help will appreciated  greatly.

Comment: Are you talking about subsets of $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology?

Comment: Brian, this is correct

Comment: I constructed a counterexample in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169714/whats-application-of-bernstein-set/169718#169718) and many counterexamples simultaneously in [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767167/mathbb-r-as-continuum-many-of-pairwise-disjoint-of-bernstein-sets/3767224#3767224).

Comment: Brain, it seems I lost my mind when I wrote my question since I know Bernstein very well but I am happy to see your construction. Thank you vert much

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: Here's one, verbatim from an old issue of Amer. Math. Monthly: A student claimed that every uncountable set of reals contains a closed uncountable subset. Is this claim true?

Answer (score 10):

(I assume that "set" here means "set of real numbers.")

Perhaps surprisingly the answer is **no**, at least assuming the axiom of choice. In fact there are very extreme counterexamples!

A [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set) is a set $B$ such that for every perfect set $P$, both $B\cap P$ and $P\setminus B$ are nonempty. Bernstein sets can be constructed via transfinite recursion *(this is a good exercise)*. And we can go further and construct Bernstein sets with various additional properties (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1534151/28111)). Bernstein sets are one of the classical types of pathological sets of reals under $\mathsf{AC}$; you've probably already seen Vitali sets, and the other two most famous types are Luzin and Sierpinski sets.

(Why must a Bernstein set have size continuum? Well, simply consider any size-continuum family of pairwise-disjoint perfect sets. Any Bernstein set has to intersect each of them, so must have size continuum.)

However, over $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone we cannot prove that Bernstein sets exist, and $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$ proves that every uncountable set of reals *does indeed* contain a perfect set (and so proves a version of the continuum hypothesis - although it also proves a version of the *negation* of the continuum hypothesis, namely that there is no injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\omega_1$).

Comment: What "version" of CH does it prove? Is it e.g. $\Bbb R\approx\omega_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N_{\ge2}$?

Comment: Noah, it seems I lost my mind when I wrote my question since I know Bernstein very well but I am happy to read your answer . Thank you vert much

Comment: @J.G. It proves that any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is either countable or contains a perfect set. So there are no cardinals strictly between $\aleph_0$ and continuum. But under AD, the continuum and $\aleph_1$ are incomparable.